# How to access datetime field of SharePoint list's attribute inside a javascript function?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to access datetime field of SharePoint list's attribute inside a javascript function?

I have a the datetime field "StartedOn", how can I access the sharepoint datafield inside the javascript?

I tried this by like this

var ppe = document.getElementById(').value;  (This is inside the Default.aspx page)

But not working, any alternative will be much helpful.

Vinu

Answer (score 0):

I worked out an alternative

1. I rendered the "StartedOn" date time value to a hidden field

   ""
2. Accessed the value inside the JavaScript function to manupulate the value in the desired format and then displayed it using "Set as InnerHtml"

   "var hdnDate=document.getElementById("hdnDateValueID0EAAA");"

Vinu